# How can I update the styling of a component based on some variable?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on an app in React Native. I want to make it so the styling of the panel labels on the bottom of the screen updates based on the panel the user is on.

As of now, I can get the index of the current panel that's showing, but I don't know how to make that update the styling of the labels.

The first panel

[image: Ther first Panel]

and the second panel

[image: The second panel]

Comment: add your code..

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you use the same component and want to style it in different ways, your component's `style` property depends on either `props` or `state`. There are many ways to put different styles depending on your state/props, I'll provide just a few of them:

1. Ternary operation based on current state.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ // Your styles go here
  labelFirstTab: {
    textColor: 'red',
  },
  labelSecondTab: {
    textColor: 'blue',
  },
});

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentTab: 0,
  };

  getLabelStyles = () => {
    const { currentTab } = this.state;
    return currentTab === 0 ? styles.labelFirstTab : styles.labelSecondTab;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* Let's say this is your label */}
        <Text style={this.getLabelStyles()}>Hi! I'm a nice label.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

2. Additional styling based on props (also could depend on state, it doesn't matter).

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textColor: 'black',
  },
  labelDarkMode: {
    textColor: 'lightgrey',
  },
}); // Your styles go here

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  getLabelStyles = () => {
    const { isDarkMode } = this.props;
    const { label, labelDarkMode } = styles;
    return [styles.label, isDarkMode && styles.labelDarkMode];
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* Let's say this is your label */}
        <Text style={this.getLabelStyles()}>Hi! I'm a nice label.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

3. You even can pass your styles directly from your props, leaving the whole logic to your parent component. Just make sure that you've passed styles from your parent component to the current one.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { labelStyles } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* Let's say this is your label */}
        <Text style={labelStyles}>Hi! I'm a nice label.</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you E. Dn! This worked! Here's what I did.

`const [activePanel, setActivePanel] = useState('nowPanel');`

Swiping between panels calls a function:

```
const swipeNavigation = (index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    setActivePanel('nowPanel');
  } else {
    setActivePanel('todayPanel');
  }
};
```

Then within the actual `View` I want to style:

```
style={activePanel === 'nowPanel' ? styles.activePanel : null,}>
```